# Flex 3: is it possible to add an event listender to a boolean variable?

Tags: apache-flex, addeventlistener

I have a boolean variable, projectsLoaded that is set to false when my application loads.  As i'm sure you can imagine, when the final project module loads, I set the variable to be true.  Is there a way I can trigger a series of functions to run once that variable is set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setters and getters to execute code when value changes. Just be sure to use the setter instead of setting the private variable value.

EDIT : I just saw you tagged your question with addeventlistener. I edited the code to use that instead.

```
private _projectsLoaded:Boolean = false;

//this could be done elsewhere, that's just an example
private function init():void
{
     addEventListener("projectsLoaded", onProjectsLoaded);
}

public function get projectsLoader():Boolean
{
    return _projectsLoaded;
}

public function set projectsLoaded(value:Boolean):void
{
    if(_projectsLoaded!=value)
    {
        _projectsLoaded = value;
        if(value)
            dispatchEvent(new Event("projectsLoaded"));
    }
}

protected function onProjectsLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    //your logic here
}
```